# How to call @setup scenario once for all the scenarios in karate

Tags: karate

I found the following implementation on how to execute the @setup scenario in the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#setup

```
Scenario Outline: 
    ...
    Examples:
    | karate.setup().kittens |
```

The problem I am having is I have a lot of scenarios outline in the feature file with already populated "Examples". And I also want the @setup to be called only once per feature file with karate.setupOnce(). So was wondering how can I achieve this? As this is for advanced karate users, I didn't find much supportive exmaples for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: there is an example in the documentation. what more do you need ? https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#setup

Comment: @PeterThomas can i know in which version the setup() was released in

Comment: in 1.3.0 https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.3.0

Comment: How are your examples organized in this file? Is it JSON? Have you tried something like: `karate.setupOnce().examples["example1"]` ?

Comment: Should karate.setupOnce() only be called from Scenario Outline and not from Scenario? Why so? Why should karate.setupOnce() be only used in "Examples" section?